# Why is my Javascript not working from the PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following files. For some reason my JavaScript (inside PHP 'echo' tags) does not work:

HTML (index.php):

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<div id="edit-box">
<INPUT type="submit" name="save-text" id="save-text" value="Save">
<textarea id="editor" name="editor">
<?php echo $content; ?>
</textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP (submit.php):

```
<?php

include('connect-db.php');

$submit_date = date("Ymd");
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));
$ip_address = getRealIPAddress();

if ($content != '') { 
mysql_query("INSERT source SET submit_date='$submit_date', ip='$ip_address', content='$content'")
or die(mysql_error());

// The following line is not working! I need help here!
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your file saved!");</script>';  

mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

The "submit.php" does not have any other PHP or HTML script/tags. I understand I am using obsolete PHP/MySQL API (instead of PDO / MySQLi), but that's beside the point.

Comment: @Pekka웃 `$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));`

Comment: @Kolink I stand corrected.

Comment: The value 'content' is being saved correctly, no issues there. But the Javascript (inside the echo tags), for reason isn't working. It seems as if it is not reaching there at all!

Comment: Well, *is* it reaching there in your browser's "view source" view? What do you see there?

Comment: BTW, you are using PHP inside `index.html` file, which is wrong. If you need php there, you should rename it to `index.php`.

Comment: @sobol6803: You know nothing about his server configuration. Maybe his server parses every file with PHP. However, in this simple case I assume you're right, as most-servers don't parse `.html` by default.

Comment: Sorry...updated. "index.html" to "index.php"...my bad.

Comment: Do your server’s logs show anything?

Comment: Again, please look at the actual output in your browser. Is the script tag there?

Comment: No...don't see the script! Can you please suggest how can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried to print something else, beside the script tags, just that you know if the scripts isn't breaking out before the `echo` statement

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your file saved!");</script>';  
Works fine, there is something else wrong.

Comment: Try to remove the query and see if it is executed, if so, it dies after executing the query. ANd thus there is something wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0):

It should should print an alert.
Are sure you are printing the script? I can see it might die on an 
error in the query.

If that is not the case, what are you including in the connect-db.php,
it might be that somewhere in the required file you are messing up 
the output buffer..

Also I'm pretty sure the sql is incorrect:

```
INSERT source SET submit_date='$submit_date', ip='$ip_address', content='$content'
```

```
INSERT INTO source (submit_date, ip, content) values('$submit_date','$ip_address','$content');
```

And that is not a secure query, however... that is beside the point.

Here is some more reasons why this could happen:

1. The `include("connect-db.php');` might kill the execution of the script.

   - If there is something wrong inside of it.
2. The query might die.
3. The output is redirected to somewhere else, in the php configuration, 
   or inside of "connect-db.php"
4. `getRealIPAddress()` is not documented, and might cause the script to break.
5. There might be something bogus in `$_POST['editor']` that might break cause
   the sql to die.

Comment: I have updated to the query you mentioned above. JS message is still not showing up though.  What is a secure query?? Can you pls share using the example above?

Comment: If you comment out the mysql_query, does is the javascript being executed then?

Comment: You are right. JS is not executed even after commenting the mysql_query line! Any ideas what might have gone wrong? PHP newbie here.

Comment: it might be that the output is being redirected to somewhere else inside the connect-db.php, also you should probably look at logs, or increase the error output to make sure you are not missing any obvoius errors.  you could try commenting out the mysql_query and removing the include and see if it is being executed.

Comment: Also it is possible that the include("connect-db.php") kills the execution.

Comment: But I could save the 'content' to the DB fine. The query and execution is working fine, since I could see it in the DB...

Comment: Sounds like the output is being redirected to somewhere else. Is anything at all being printed to the screen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25894/discussion-between-pal-tonder-and-mumbo-jumbo)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
<?php

include('connect-db.php');

$submit_date = date("Ymd");
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));
$ip_address = getRealIPAddress();
$content = $_POST["editor"];
if ($content != '') { 
mysql_query("INSERT source SET submit_date='$submit_date', ip='$ip_address', content='$content'")
or die(mysql_error());

// The following line is not working! I need help here!
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your file saved!");</script>';  

mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed?

Comment: try to print $contents and see, what you get first.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Vishnu circumvented the `mysql_real_escape_string`, which actually makes no sense in order to fix this. After all, if the escaped string contains no data, it cannot be inserted and thus no message is needed.

Comment: Explanation : You dont have any value in $content, I have used $content = $_POST["editor"]; to get the value of text area.

Comment: $_POST['editor'] is the variable you might want to check if it's empty, that IF is blocking the flowcode to that line that 'its not working'

Comment: Why would you want to circuvent `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: Value in the 'content' variable is successfully being save to the DB, but the following JS line is not executing.